# Setting value of [(ngModel)] upon first page load in Angular 2

Tags: data-binding, typescript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I am trying to create a simple `select` component which takes in some data via attributes and renders the required options. I plan to use this select component inside the template of another component, say `PageComponent`'s template( **page.template.html** ).

I am binding a variable of PageComponent to the `select` component using `[(ngModel)]`. Upon selecting an option, the value of the variable get's updated as expected but how do I set it to point to the first option upon page load without triggering a manual selection on the `select` component?

Here's the code.

#### In page.template.html

```
<select ui-select 
        [options]="options" 
        [(ngModel)]="alertType"
        [defaultValue]="'Select an alert Type'">
</select>
{{alertType}} <!-- To see the value while debugging -->
```

#### In page.component.ts, `PageComponent` class

```
alertType:any;
options = [
    {id:1, value:"item-1"},
    {id:2, value:"item-2"},
    {id:3, value:"item-3"}
];
```

#### In select.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: '[ui-select]',
  template: `
    <option *ngIf="defaultValue" value="-1">{{defaultValue}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">{{option.value}}</option>
  `
})
export class SelectComponent {
  @Input() options: any;
  @Input() defaultValue: string;
}
```

Right now, the `{{alertType}}` value initially shows nothing and updates only upon selecting a new option from the `select` box.

I do understand that it's happening because `alertType` is set to undefined by default in `PageComponent` but I can't figure out how to set it to the first option value when the page loads.

## Update

The original question has been answered but I had one more question regarding this so updated the question.

In the updated code, the `select` component accepts a `defaultValue` custom property from the template and renders a conditional `<option>` for that default value.

Now, how do I say that if `defaultValue` is set, `alertType` should have that value or otherwise it should have the value of the first item in the `options` list.

### P.S - If you have comments about the approach used in building the component, please feel free to add them in answers as it will help me learn.

Comment: "if defaultValue is set" - set from where? Programmatically or via the select element?

Comment: set from `page.template.html` in the `select` box as custom property. Above it's done as `[defaultValue]="'Select an alert Type'"`

Answer (score 5):

So you want `alertType` should be set to the selected value, whether it could be from your provided `options` or from your `defaultValue`(first option).

this could be done by using `AfterViewInit` hook,

the modified code will be..

```
@Component({  
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives:[ 
    SelectComponent
  ],
  template : `<select ui-select
        [options]="options"
        [(ngModel)]="alertType"
        [defaultValue]="'Select an alert Type'" #mySelect>
</select>
{{alertType}}`
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('mySelect', {read: ViewContainerRef}) mySelect;
options = [
    {id: 1, value: "item-1", selected: false},
    {id: 2, value: "item-2", selected: true},//if all options will be false then defaultValue will be selected
    {id: 3, value: "item-3", selected: false}
];
alertType: any;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.alertType = this.mySelect.element.nativeElement.value;
  }

}
```

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lWgz9Rjf7ghPcr3wrgpf?p=preview), check this!!

Answer (score 2):

You could try it like so:

```
options = [
    {id:1, value:"item-1"},
    {id:2, value:"item-2"},
    {id:3, value:"item-3"}
];

alertType: any = options[0].id;
```

Comment: Shit! that is so simple and I was going around the world thinking what not. :/ I actually have further question so let me update the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For your new question, you could leverage the `selected` attribute in your ui-select component:

```
<option *ngIf="defaultValue" selected="true" value="-1">{{defaultValue}}</option>
```

Comment: would that also set the initial value of the `alertType` variable in PageComponent used as `[(ngModel)]` for the select box?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't set the value of `alertType` until i actually select an option